# (<any>window) How to check if package is installed

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a value of `undefined` for my `var ne` and I am not sure why. The object `this.noteEditorElementId` is returning a `textarea`. I am thinking it's something to do with the `(<any>window)` is there a way I can check that the package is installed?

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

```js
            var $noteDescription = $("#" + this.noteEditorElementId, this.elementRef.nativeElement);
            (<any>window).CKEDITOR.replace($noteDescription.get(0));
            var ne = this.noteEditor = (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances[this.noteEditorElementId];
            console.log(ne);
     ne.on("change", () => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    console.log(ne.getData());
                    this.cloneModel.ReferenceText = ne.getData();
                });
            });
```

Comment: you could do optional chaining `ne?.on()`.

Comment: Yes but I am thinking it will never make that change event .

Comment: Can I do (<any>window) on a element Id in the console ?

Comment: Please provide html code, if possible provide stackblitz example

Comment: yes... it is possible to check whether the package is installed or not... after installing packages, you will get the node modules folder go and check there

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction of this problem?

Comment: Hi. Do you have installed @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular and @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic?. Hope to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you not sure if package is installed, just look it on package.json and write in terminal: `npm i`

also maybe you forgot to import that package to your component and module.